# Convert a Red Black Tree into a 2, 4 tree

Tags: java, data-structures, red-black-tree

So as you have probably guessed I am trying to convert a red black tree into a 2,4 tree in Java. I am not so much stuck on how this works but more of figuring out the best way to traverse through the tree.

Going to be using a pre-constructed redblack tree so I must somehow gather the information from each node and then build the new 2,4 tree node by node.

I am thinking of using an array based implementation as I kind of 'transition' stage. So for example at array[i] its left child is array[i(*2)] and its right child is array[(i*2)+1)]. Then looping through the array and building the 2,4 from there by grabbing its information (i.e whether it has red or black children / parents) and form each 2,4 node.

This seems pretty inefficient but thus far this is all I have been able to come up with.

Any other recommendations?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6598515/complexity-of-turning-a-sorted-array-to-a-2-4-b-tree).

Specifically "a black node with two black children is a 2 node, a black node with one red child is a 3 node, and a black node with two red children is a 4 node" - you can use this directly for the conversion.